# Custom button in leftBarButtonItems to function as backBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode4.6, backbarbuttonitem

I am using leftBarButtonItems to group a negativeSeparator (to get rid of padding and align my custom button to the edge of the screen) and a custom UIBarButtonItem:

```
[navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[negativeSeperator, leftButton]];
```

How do I make my custom leftButton function as a backBarButtonItem? I understand that as soon as I use leftBarButtonItems, it hides/replaces the backBarButtonItem. So, how can I "transfer" the back button functionality to my custom button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the action to the leftBarButton item you are placing on the navigationBar and add the below code in that action method

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I probably should have mentioned that I want to implement this by not having to make method calls (because I would then have to do it on every viewController). I know I can set leftBarButtonItem to be backBarButtonItem. But can I set leftBarButtonItems (probably not as it's an array) or a button in that array to be backBarButtonItem?

Comment: Thanks, I'll just create these simple methods in each view controller then